# Converting existing controller actions into Generic methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

In my ASP.NET 5 Web API project I find that many of my core controllers contain the exact same CRUD methods. I find that I'm simply copying/pasting the code and searching and replacing the main type. Alarm bells! That triggered this thought: If possible, I would like to create a generic implementation of these actions to reduce the similar code. This would help code maintainability, etc.

Any suggestions on how I do this? Here is one sample class, used by VehicleType. My other classes (Organizations, Countries, etc) are **very similar** and all contain methods to do the following: **GetAll, Get, Create, Update and Delete**.

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class VehicleTypeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly ILogger<VehicleTypeController> _logger;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public VehicleTypeController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ILogger<VehicleTypeController> logger, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _logger = logger;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var countries = await _unitOfWork.VehicleTypes.GetAll();

        var results = _mapper.Map<IList<VehicleTypeDTO>>(countries);

        return Ok(results);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = "Get")]    
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        var VehicleType = await _unitOfWork.VehicleTypes.Get(i => i.Id == id);

        var results = _mapper.Map<VehicleTypeDTO>(VehicleType);

        return Ok(results);
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] CreateVehicleTypeDTO VehicleTypeDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Invalid POST attempt in {nameof(CreateVehicleType)}");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var VehicleType = _mapper.Map<VehicleType>(VehicleTypeDto);
        await _unitOfWork.VehicleTypes.Insert(VehicleType);
        await _unitOfWork.Save();

        return CreatedAtRoute("Get", new { id = VehicleType.Id }, VehicleType);
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    [HttpPut("{id:int}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, [FromBody] UpdateVehicleTypeDTO VehicleTypeDto)    
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid || id < 1)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Invalid UPDATE attempt in {nameof(Update)}");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var VehicleType = await _unitOfWork.VehicleTypes.Get(a => a.Id == id);
        if (VehicleType == null)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Submitted data is invalid.");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _mapper.Map(VehicleTypeDto, VehicleType);
        _unitOfWork.VehicleTypes.Update(VehicleType);
        await _unitOfWork.Save();

        return NoContent();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    [HttpDelete("{id:int}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        if (id < 1)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Invalid DELETE attempt in {nameof(Delete)}");
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var VehicleType = _unitOfWork.VehicleTypes.Get(i => i.Id == id);
        if (VehicleType == null)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Invalid DELETE attempt in {nameof(Delete)}");
            return BadRequest("Submitted data is invalid.");
        }

        await _unitOfWork.VehicleTypes.Delete(id);
        await _unitOfWork.Save();

        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

Is the best approach to create an interface with these methods then have these class implement this interface? For example something like this....

```
public interface IGenericCRUD
{
    Task<IActionResult> Get();
    Task<IActionResult> Get(int id);
    Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] object myDto);
    Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, [FromBody] object myDto);
    Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id);
}
```

Then use reflection to dyamically call the appropriate methods based on the generic type?

So, create a generic CRUD class that implements IGenericCRUD and that contains the core CRUD code, but use a generic T. Something like...

```
public class GenericCrud<T, TEntityDto>
```

Then, in the Get method, for example, something like this? (It doesn't compile so I'm not sure if I'm close.)

```
    public async Task<IList<TEntityDto>> Get()
    {
        var getAllResults = await _unitOfWork.GetType(T).GetAll();

        var results = _mapper.Map<IList<TEntityDto>>(getAllResults);

        return results;
    }
```

Am I on the right track? Any way to post a "generic" version of this class to let me see your approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you need this interface, but usually using `object` for such "unification" is discouraged. If you want to reduce code duplication you can create an actual generic `GenericCRUDBase<>` where you will list all generic types you need like  `GenericCRUDBase<EntityDTO, CreateEntityDTO, UpdateEntityDTO>` and change everything accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @GuruStron! Can you create a sample class for only one simple Get method to show me what you mean? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Look into `Generic Repository Patterns` it is essentially what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in comments you can try to do something like this:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CRUDControllerBase<T, TDto, TCreate, TUpdate> : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly ILogger<CRUDControllerBase<T,TDto, TCreate, TUpdate>> _logger;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public VehicleTypeController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ILogger<CRUDControllerBase<T, TDto, TCreate, TUpdate>> logger, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _logger = logger;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IList<TDto>> Get()
    {
        // if you have used simple EF db context you could use here 
        // .Set<T>().ToListAsync() here  
        var countries = await _unitOfWork.XXX.GetAll();

        var results = _mapper.Map<IList<TDto>>(countries);

        return results;
    }
```

And then `VehicleTypeController` would be `VehicleTypeController:CRUDControllerBase<VehicleType, VehicleTypeDTO, CreateVehicleTypeDTO, UpdateVehicleTypeDTO>`. The only problem would  figuring out the `_unitOfWork.XXX` part. Again, as I wrote in the comment in the code, if you were using EF core `DbContext` it has [`Set<TEntity>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-5.0) convenience method exactly for this types of situations, but without actual implementation of `IUnitOfWork` it is hard to say what you should do. Implementing something like `Set` with a little bit of reflection can be a solution, or creating a generic `IUnitOfWork<TEntity>` interface and injecting it into the controller can be another.